# How to dynamically subscribe to a Redis channel with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis

In the code below, I have the array *channels*, which is processed at the startup of the app.

I am running into an issue trying to dynamically add and subscribe a new redis channel through the /channels/add/id route.

Is this even possible? (to be able to re-initialize the channels array and then subscribe to a new channel ?)

My only current idea on how achieve it would be to write the channel names to a file, which would then be read during start up and have a cron restart the app. This would be a very bad way to do it and I hope there is a better solution.

Thank you for your time.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var fs = require("fs");
var redis = require("redis");
var channel = [];
var channels = ['channel1', 'channel2'];

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
});

app.set('views', __dirname + '/tpl');
app.set('view engine', "jade");
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("page");
});

app.get('/channel/add/:id', function(req, res) {
    var c = channels.length + 1;
    channel[c] = redis.createClient();
    channel[c].subscribe(req.params.id);
    channel[c].on("message", function(channel, message) {
        io.sockets.emit('message', {message: message, channel: channel});
    });
    res.send('Channel Started: ' + req.params.id);
});

app.get('/channel/list', function(req, res) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(channels));
});


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
console.log("Listening on port " + port);

for (var i in channels) {
    channel[i] = redis.createClient();
    channel[i].subscribe(channels[i]);
    channel[i].on("message", function(channel, message) {
        io.sockets.emit('message', {message: message, channel: channel});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the list of channels in redis also? That way you're getting more use out of something you already have (vs installing MySQL or some other database to store the information).